# Logo on Google AMP cards is not displayed in Google Search results

Tags: google-search, mobile, schema.org, search-results, amp

Recently I started working on this news portal http://tichyseinblick.de. Its desktop and mobile/responsive version are quite bad in terms SEO and performance (inline scripts, non-progressive/compressed images etc), but in this case it doesn't really matter, because it has some weird problem with logo displayed on AMP cards in Google Search results.

Unlike the regular version AMP pages do implement schema.org JSON-LD metadata, including publisher.logo property

[image]

The logo is a the recommended by google dark-on-light text, width <= 600px and height = 60px, non-vector image etc
...but for some reason it's still not displayed on AMP cards in Google Search results:

## Image no.1: Tichys Einblick (out website)

[image: RTY AMP card]

## Image no.2: another German news portal (works correctly)

[image: Zeit Online AMP card]

If expanded both AMP previews are displayed correctly:

[image: RTY AMP card preview]

[image: Zeit Online AMP card preview]

The only BIG difference between two websites is that the other one uses inline Microdata instead of JSON-LD, is it critical? Is it what Google Crawler wants to "see" when it fetchers AMP pages in order to create AMP cards?

Comment: [Cross-post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40483760/1591669)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, the meta data for the organisation is drawn from the Desktop version of the site. Add the schema data for the Organisation thing there and it will appear for other versions.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I will add JSON-LD data to the regular version and make sure there it contains publisher -> logo info too. If it works I will accept the answer

Comment: I combined your answer with the one I got on Google Webmaster Central Help Forum (apparently logo's URL I used in JSON-LD metadata was blocked by robots.txt file) and it worked. So thanks for helping me out